# What does this mean? "we're not going to make the guilt worse by telling that listening is a good thing, worthy but in fact rather dull."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Many of us probably have a nagging feeling that we don't listen enough to other people. Here we're not going to make the guilt worse by telling you that listening is a good thing, worthy but in fact rather dull.

Hear [more](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=43e51vkffQE).

I can't actually understand the meaning of this paragraph.

Finally, What happened to listening, is it a good thing or not?

What does the author mean by these words ("worthy", "rather"(fairly?), "dull"(boring?) here?
Worthy? I wonder if it means trying to help people or deserving respect from them. (And what does the word "worthy" refer to? Listening? Then why after saying that we're not gonna telling you that listening is a good thing?)

What's the result? Is this conclusion accurate?

> The author is saying that we don't want to repeat it and say that listening is a good thing (maybe because this attitude toward this matter has became a stereotype) so we think it is a worthy activity, it requires attention, it deserves respect but partly it is boring, it's not interesting and therefore it's not exciting.

Comment: Please look those words up and then explain why the dictionary definitions do not shed light.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo More info added.

Answer (score 1):

> Many of us probably have a nagging feeling that we don't listen enough
>   to other people. Here we're not going to make the guilt worse by
>   telling you that listening is a good thing, worthy but in fact rather
>   dull.

We are not going to make your nagging guilt worse
by telling you that listening is a good thing,
an action that deserves your attention <sup>worthy</sup>
though it <sup>listening</sup> is actually quite boring.

It is somewhat "tongue-in-cheek".  If you feel that you do not listen enough to what other people have to say, it would only make your sense of guilt worse if we were to tell you that listening is a good thing to do, that it is something that really deserves your attention, but quite boring.  So we are not going to say that to you.